# How to handle exceptions with DataFrame.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, exception, apply

I want to `DataFrame.apply()` `dateutil.parser.parse` to a pandas dataframe column of date strings, but some cells are `NaN`, so it raises an exception. What is the pandastyle way to deal with this?

Should I write another function replacing `parse()` to handle the errors and apply that instead? Deal with it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert not parseable values to `NaT` (`NaN` for datetime in pandas):

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], errors='coerce')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2015-01-01 19:00:20', np.nan, '2015-02-03 17:00:00', 'NA']})
print (df)
                  date
0  2015-01-01 19:00:20
1                  NaN
2  2015-02-03 17:00:00
3                   NA

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
                 date
0 2015-01-01 19:00:20
1                 NaT
2 2015-02-03 17:00:00
3                 NaT

print (df['date'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your current method work, you could add a if else to check if the value is nan.

```
df.apply(lambda x: your_functions(x['col']) if pd.notnull(x['col']) else np.nan,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer certainly works for the specific example brought up.  However, Pandas does seem to lack a generic way for handling transformation exceptions.  I recently released a pandas-mapper package that can solve this more generically (https://github.com/inside-track/pandas-mapper).

In the case mentioned above, pandas-mapper can be used to redirect error records to another dataframe that could then be handled accordingly.  For example, suppose we had a dataframe with both "name" and "birthdate" columns that we had to transform to both parse the string date and to capitalize the names.  pandas-mapper could then be used like

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_mapper
import dateutil

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['alice', 'george', 'sam'],
    'birthdate': ['1996-01-01', '1997-06-21', 'Yesterday'],
})

mapping = df.mapping(
    [
        ('name', 'name', lambda v: v.capitalize()),
        ('birthdate', 'birthdate', dateutil.parser.parse),
    ],
    on_error='redirect'
)
```

The `mapping` object has both `mapped` and `errors` attributes which are dataframes containing the mapped records and the error records.

`mapping.mapped`:

```
| name   | birthdate  |
| -      | -          |
| Alice  | 1996-01-01 |
| George | 1997-06-21 |
```

`mapping.errors`:

```
| name   | birthdate  | __error__                                         |
| -      | -          | -                                                 |
| sam    | Yesterday  | {'msg': 'ValueError(Yesterday): ('Unknown stri... |
```